# Atualizar item do ListView após de Callback

Tags: android, parse.com

Na minha aplicação, eu utilizo o `SDK` do `Parse.com`. O SDK fornece um método para carregar objetos da API de forma `assíncrona` e em outra `thread` chamado `fetchInBackground()`. Dentro do `getView()` do meu `adapter` acontece o seguinte:

```
ParseObject driver = object.getParseObject("object");
    driver.fetchInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
            if(e==null){
                item.name.setText(parseObject.getString("name"));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
});
```

Eu estou tentando setar o nome no `item.name` que é um `TextView`, mas o nome só aparece quando eu rolo a lista e retorno, no caso quando carrega novamente o item.

Comment: Você sabia que o Parse.com irá morrer no fim do ano né?

Comment: Sim @LeonardoDias. Mas isso não me impede de usar o SDK deles, até porque já é um projeto existente há um tempo.. Basta clonar o servidor deles..

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar

```
     View v = suaListView.getChildAt(position);
     TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.idSuaTextView);
     textView.setText(parseObject.getString("name");
```

ou então utilize RecyclerView e no RecyclerView.Adapter no método

```
    onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position){
        MyViewHolder holder = (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;

        holder.seuTextView.setText("Texto atualizado");

        notifyItemChanged(position);
     }
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html

Espero ter ajudado :)